# Switching between DataGrid and ListView

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to implement a functionality where user can select type of view on Combobox. Based on selection either DataGrid or ListView will display given data.

My question here is:
What is the correct way to implement this?

Do I set Visibility property on DataGrid and ListView based on selection of the Combobox or is there another "cleaner" way to do this (referring to clean-code principles)?

Comment: Why would you want to do this at all? Why not just a datagrid?

Comment: That's the acceptance criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `ContentControl` with a `Style` that triggers on the selected value in the `ComboBox`, e.g.:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"
          SelectedIndex="0">
    <s:String>DataGrid</s:String>
    <s:String>ListBox</s:String>
</ComboBox>

<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataGrid>
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="..." />
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=cmb}" Value="ListBox">
                    <Setter Property="Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ListBox>
                                <ListBoxItem>1</ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem>2</ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem>3</ListBoxItem>
                            </ListBox>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

[image]